# Запись множества значений в БД

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

Есть локальная БД от MS Access 2003, работаем через Jet.OLEDB.4.0. В приложении составляется буфер из множества записей, который надо закинуть в базу.
Как составить один большой запрос на запись в БД?

```
        dbCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table] (AccDate) VALUES (@dateParam)";

        dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@dateParam", OleDbType.Date);

        foreach (TrendDataRow row in trendDataRowList)
            // Добавляем множество значений к запросу

        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: TrendDataRow  -- это наследник DataRow? вы используете DataTable?

Comment: если да, то надо использовать OleDbDataAdapter. пример [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Нет, TrendDataRow это класс, в котором определена переменная, которая должна попасть в базу.

Comment: _"TrendDataRow это класс"_ -- есть код этого класса?

Comment: На данном этапе кроме "public DateTime time;" в нем нет ничего. Будет несколько параметров и возможно понадобятся гетеры с обработкой. Планирую создавать экземпляр этого класса, брать данные из другой программы, складывать их в него. Экземпляры в список, а при достижении определенного значения все экземпляры пишем в базу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    dbCommand.CommandText = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < trendDataRowList.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dbCommand.CommandText += string.Format("\nINSERT INTO [table] (AccData) VALUES (@param{0})", i.ToString());
        var param = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = string.Format("@param{0}", i.ToString());
        param.DbType = OleDbType.Date;
        param.Value = trendDataRowList.Rows[i]["AccDate"]; // или что вам там нужно
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
    }

    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```